Snakemake fails to execute the preample when executing --edit-notebook inside a virtualenv
I have the python packages notebook and snakemake installed in my user site-packages.
To use snakemake with different setups, I use virtualenvs. In this virtualenv I installed snakemake and all the requirements of my workflow.
When I try to edit a notebook using
snakemake --cores 1 --edit-notebook <output>

the notebook server opens up and I can edit the notebook. But when I try to execute the snakemake preamble (the first cell that is automatically inserted by Snakemake) I get the following error:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'AttributeGuard' on <module 'snakemake.io' from '$HOME/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/io.py'>

This is weird because snakemake is installed in my virtualenv:
$ which snakemake
~/.virtualenvs/<virtualenv>/bin/snakemake


TL;DR:
Install notebook in the virtualenv:
pip install notebook



Snakemake apparently uses the executable notebook to start the notebooks.
If this executable is installed outside the virtualenv, the kernels are not started from within the virtualenv
This particular issue may be due to different versions of snakemake being used inside and outside the virtualenv.
In fact, in the virtualenv: snakemake==8.25.3, in the user site-packages: snakemake==8.8.0


This illustrates well why it's easiest to avoid site-packages and use only virtual environments. For each project, create its own venv, install everything it needs there, and everything will be coherent.
